# Node cli argument parser for git-like commands

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a simple git-like cli argument parser like this:

```
$ app [global-options] command [command-options]
```

I tried [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/), [gitlike-cli](https://github.com/jedmao/gitlike-cli), and few other cli parser libs---none of them seem to support segregation of global options from command-options.

[commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) seems to be supporting it. But when I delved deeper, I found issues. For example, I wanted a `-v` global option that would enable verbosity at global level. All I did was to set `global.verbose = true;` in `index.js`, and in the command specific `index-subcmd.js`, when I read `global.verbose`, it is not set!

Am I missing something obvious, or is my understanding correct that node ecosystem is lacking a lib with this functionality? Coming from Java background, I really miss [airline](https://github.com/airlift/airline).

Comment: Started my own implementation for the reported usecase: [WizTools.org Cli Parse](https://github.com/wiztools/wiz-cliparse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a cli parsing library to support the usecase: [wiz-cliparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiz-cliparse).

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to point out a library I wrote after being disappointed with the popular CLI tools. I created [wily-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wily-cli) to compete against those big name tools by providing more customization and CLI features, and attempting to be easier to use. Subhash's [wiz-cliparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiz-cliparse) should definitely be able to help your use case, but if you need to create a more powerful CLI, I might recommend looking into wily-cli. For your use case, those "global options" would essentially be the the options of your initial command (from your example, that would be `app`). When creating an option, you would set the `passThrough` flag in the option configuration...

```
.option('example', 'Example option', { passThrough: true });
```

This will set the option to also be passed down to children/gandchildren/etc. commands